# Finding hostname of devices in a network using SNMP

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, snmp, hostname

Is it possible to get the hostname of all devices in a network using SNMP. Is it possible to achieve it through python programming. could you please suggest the appropriate package for this in python

Comment: What is "all devices in a network"? All devices in  LAN? In a subnet? Once you clarify that, you can go onto the next part of the problem. What is the "hostname"? If you are referring to a FQDN, then query your DNS server. Else, you can query sysName.0 .

Comment: I need to get the device name of each device in the entire network that comprises different subnets.